# C# Find a matching string by regex

Tags: c#, regex

I want to find out, whether my string contains a text like #1, #a, #abc, #123, #abc123dsds and so on... ('#' character with one or more characters (digits and letters).

My code so far won't work:

```
string test = "#123";
boolean matches = test.Contains("#.+");
```

The `matches` variable is `false`.

Comment: `String.Contains` does not accept a regex. Use `Regex.IsMatch(test, "#.+")`.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using `boolean` instead of `bool`?

Comment: If you are after letters and digits explicetely, then you could use `[A-Za-z0-9]` instead of `.`, because as is you could simply use `.startsWith("#")` and `.length > 1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`String.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) does not accept a regex.

Use [`Regex.IsMatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdx2bds0(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var matches = Regex.IsMatch(test, "#.+");
```

Comment: If you really need to check for letters and digits only, you can use `@"#[\p{L}\d]+"` pattern.

Answer (score 2):

`test.Contains("#.+");` does not "understand" regular expressions. It literally checks if the string `test` literally contains `#.+` sequence of characters, which `#123` does not contain.

Use [`Regex.IsMatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdx2bds0(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
bool matches = Regex.IsMatch(test, "#.+");
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/m3Io8H)

Answer (score 2):

Or without regex, you can use a combination of [`StartsWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith), [`Enumerable.Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any) and [`char.IsLetterOrDigit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isletterordigit) methods like;

```
var s = "#abc123dsds+";
var matches = s.Length > 1 && s.StartsWith("#") && s.Substring(1).All(char.IsLetterOrDigit);
```

Comment: Why is regex better than `s.StartsWith("#") && s.Substring(1).All(Char.IsLetterOrDigit)`? However, currently it also accepts `#` as valid.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Just my opinion because it is more simpler than my solution. And as you said, `##` or `###` are does not match in my answer.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Wait a second, it shouldn't match because `#` is not a letter of course. I delete that sentences. My answer is better. HAHA :)

Comment: But it still allows `"#"` as match even if # should be followed by a letter or digit. So a `Length > 1` is required. It's subjective but imo string methods are simpler.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Right. I think `?:` solve this. Updated.

Comment: Imo that's a perfect use case for the `&&`- instead of the conditional-operator ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Okey, you won :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Regex in order to use a regex pattern.

```
string text = "#123";
Regex rgx = new Regex("#[a-zA-Z0-9]+");
var match = rgx.Match(text);
bool matche = match.Success)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this worked for me. \# checks if it starts with #, \w checks if it is a word.

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = "#2";
        string pat = @"\#(\w+)";

        Regex r = new Regex(pat);

        Match m = r.Match(text);

        Console.WriteLine(m.Success);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```